# Create/Overwrite a file in a local repo folder using powerShell

Tags: json, git, powershell

I have a JSON file that I am updating in powershell and I want to create/overwrite that file in my local repo folder so I can commit it. I am trying to do this through powershell but I keep getting an error Permission denied. I do have access to that folder because it is on my local machine

Script

```
$myJsonFile = $json | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100

New-Item -Path "C:\Desktop\Testing" -ItemType File -Value $myJsonFile
```

I cloned an empty repo inside that folder and now trying to create a file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn’t name your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the following and add the name of the file

```
$json | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File ""C:\Desktop\Testing\Test.json"
```